# Blazor @code properties being reset to null when leaving functions

Tags: c#, json, blazor

I am new to blazor, so this is probably something stupid simple.  I am setting some public properties OnInitializedAsync, but upon leaving it resets them to null for some reason.  I have tried tracking down the reason, but I can't find anything causing it other than that I picked up some bad coding habits during my self-teaching.

```
@using System.Text.Json;
@using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
@using myFirstBlazorSite.Components.root.models;

@page "/"

<p>@jsonTest.Cheeses[0].Producer.Name</p>

@code {
    private CheeseJson _jsonTest;
    public CheeseJson jsonTest { 
        get { return _jsonTest; } 
        set { 
            _jsonTest = value; 
            if (_jsonTest == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Json was cleared");
            } 
        }
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CheeseItUp();

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void CheeseItUp()
    {
        string jsonFile = $"C:\\Users\\MacGuffin_\\source\\repos\\myFirstBlazorSite\\TestFiles\\CheeseJson\\Cheese1.json";

        StreamReader r = new(jsonFile);

        string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
        CheeseJson jsonTest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CheeseJson>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

The json deserializer works fine, and loads the expected properties. But once I leave the function it becomes null again.  Tried to track it down with private fields, but just resets it without triggering the WriteLine.

Comment: I think in CheeseItUp you should not be re-declaring a local variable jsonTest. Wrong --> `CheeseJson jsonTest = ...` instead, just `jsonTest = ...` to use the class member.

Comment: Also by convention, class members should be PascalCase in csharp :) `JsonTest`, for a class member, `jsonTest` for a local variable.

Comment: @topsail That fixed it! And good shout about the casing, I am normally better about that but was on autopilot trying to figure out this issue :p